# Table Header Only Over Column 1 MUI v5 React Code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

does anyone know why in the following code block, my Table Headers are only showing up above the first column? I noticed that if I change the Table body to not slice the first row then it will who up aligned as anticipated. However, I want to make this table editable, sortable, and read/write so I need to separate the headers from the table body data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody } from "@mui/material";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import dataCsv from "./LabData4VeslWebapp.csv";

function TableTestD3() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.text(dataCsv).then((csvText) => {
      const parsedData = d3.csvParseRows(csvText);
      setTableData(parsedData);
    });
  }, []);

  const headers = tableData.length > 0 ? tableData[0] : [];

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {headers.map((header, index) => (
              <TableCell align="center" key={index}>
                {header}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {tableData.slice(1).map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
                <TableCell align="center" key={cellIndex}>
                  {cell}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default TableTestD3;
```

Result I am getting from this code:

[Picture of the table I get with the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMlm.png)